# Tkinter change coordinates and size of a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering how I can change the coordinates and size of a button. I know you can do `button1.pack(side=RIGHT)` but what if I want to say `button1.pack(x=100, y=40)`. I have tried `button1.geometry` but that hasn't worked.

Answer:
I did `button1.place(x=0, y=0)` and the button went to the top corner. 
Here is the code I used if anybody is curious:

```
from tkinter import *

t = Tk()

t.title("Testing")

t.geometry("250x250")

MyButton = Button(t, text="Click Me")

MyButton.pack()

def Clicked(event):

    MyButton.place(x=0, y=0)

MyButton.bind("<Button-1>" ,Clicked)

MyButton.pack()

t.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `x,y` only with layout manager `place()` but then you shouldn't use other layout managers - `pack()`, `grid()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tkinter` has three layout managers

- [Grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)
- [Pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)
- [Place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)

You can use `x,y` with `place()` but then rather you shouldn't use other managers which calculate position automatically and they may have problem when you put something manually using `pack()`.

But you may put `Frame` (using `place()`) and use other manager inside `Frame`

`pack()` and `grid()` are more popular because they calculate positions automatically when you change size or you use on different system.

---

Example created few days ago for other question.

`Button` moves `Frame` in random position.

**EDIT:** now `Button` moves itself to random position and changes height.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- function ---

def move():
    #b.place_forget() # it seems I don't have to use it 
                      # to hide/remove before I put in new place
    new_x = random.randint(0, 100)
    new_y = random.randint(0, 150)
    b.place(x=new_x, y=new_y)

    b['height'] = random.randint(1, 10)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text='Move it', command=move)
b.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if I wanted it to go to random coordinates when the program starts?

Comment: use random values at start in palce of `x=0, y=0`, or run `move()` after `b.place(x=0, y=0)`